# jenkins parallel overwriting my functional test reports

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have several functional tests (using testng) that take about an hour to complete. I figured I'd run it in parallel, however at the end of the execution I'm only seeing one report.

Any ideas how to prevent this from happening?

The maven command that's being executed is a little long to copy/paste it here.

Comment: You could just add a copy statement once each parallel stage finishes to move the file somewhere else so that it doesn't get overwritten

Comment: Yeah I guess I was hoping there might be an out of the box solution for this. How do others do this when they have a large number of tests? Is this something everyone has to handle themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload result as junit report under different name for each parallel

Comment: I'll try this out. I'm guessing there's nothing out of the box to enable this? Do you know what the best/recommended approach is to running a large number of functional tests other than just running them in parallel?

Comment: @Spider If you have no resource limitation, parallel is the best practice